Can I use two remotes with one local repo and use one of the remotes just to sync desktop and laptop?
I have a local git repo. I push and pull to a remote repo that I share with colleagues and don't want to push unfinished and untested changes.
I have a desktop and a laptop computer on which I want to work on the same project and I want them to be in sync. Basically I want to sync unfinished and untested changes just so I can switch from office to home office and just continue on my laptop computer without losing changes and without having to commit trash to the remote I share with others.

Does putting the entire project including git files into the cloud and syncing across devices (desktop and laptop) work? My intuition is that is a bad idea. Which brings me to:

Can I use my private Github account to add as a second remote and commit and push/pull to and fro my two devices (desktop and laptop) and only push/pull to the "main" remote when I am ready to? What would the workflow look like? Would it involve branches? If so, how exactly? Have one "work_in_progress" branch that I just push to my private remote? Can one push a branch to just one remote and not have it influence the other remote?


I tried 1) before which made onedrive create multiple copies of certain files, which I don't want. I want to have a "local" repo that pushes to / pulls from "main" remote but also is in sync across two devices (desktop and laptop).

Can you login using your work account in your home office laptop, and pull from the main remote ? Also what is wrong with creating a untested-branch in your official remote, and using that to sync between devices ? Is there a policy against pushing untested code to any random branch ?

When you say you don't want to push to the remote repo you share with colleagues, are you saying you would be pushing to the main branch? I agree that this wouldn't be good, since nobody wants trash on the main branch. But I don't see anything wrong with making a branch yourself, and even calling it "my-work-in-progress", and syncing with that branch in that repo from all your computers. This way it wouldn't be messing with the main branch, and a branch named like that would expect to have code that's not working right yet. Then merge from that into the main branch when you're ready. With git, branches are cheap, so make as many as you like. Personally, I would go with this approach.
As for storing code in your personal repo, you should probably first check with the higher-ups to see if they have a problem keeping official code on a non-official server. If they agree, then I think that would work fine. Your local git project can happily have multiple remotes, if you know how to deal with them. You can pull and push to each one as needed.

The best way to do this would be to have ssh access to your desktop.
If so, you can add your desktop as a remote git remote add username@url:/path/to/directory/.git
If you do not have access to this, you could still push to the main repository on a branch, eventually under the name <username>/branchName, and not tie it to an open merge/pull request. This has the advantage of having your code be available to others should it be needed (holiday, or something happens that does not allow you to work etc).
Eventually, you can also create a private repo on github, add it as a remote and push a copy of the code. This can also be achieved by creating a fork of the project. However, your company might not appreciate or allow this, as it basically exfiltrate company code to a personal space they do not control. If that is an issue, I recommand checking with them to see if you can host individual forks under the company's organisation. I know GitLab allows this by forking under a user's namespace.
